# Python скрипт после упаковки pyinstaller перестаёт обрабатывать кириллицу в путях файлов

Tags: python-3.x, кодировка, pyinstaller, exe

Простой скрипт работает, когда запускаю его через командную строку. Но после упаковки его в exe с помощью pyinstaller он перестаёт воспринимать кириллицу в пути к файлу/папке. Если убрать кириллицу, то отрабатывает как должен.

Вот часть кода, которая не работает:

```
# coding=utf-8
import io, csv

exp_list = [
    ['Date','Title','Base Point Id','BP X','BP Y','BP Z','Survey Point Id','SP X','SP Y','SP Z'],
    ['Date','Title','Base Point Id','BP X','BP Y','BP Z','Survey Point Id','SP X','SP Y','SP Z'],
    ['Date','Title','Base Point Id','BP X','BP Y','BP Z','Survey Point Id','SP X','SP Y','SP Z']
    ]

path_csv =r'C:\Евгений\2022 Работа\202212\20221219 тест\1_Document.csv'
try:
    with io.open(path_csv, 'w', encoding='utf8') as file_w:
        file_w_writer = csv.writer(file_w, delimiter=';', lineterminator='\n')
        for row in exp_list:
            file_w_writer.writerow(row)
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))

print('Done')
input('>')
```

Ошибка:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Евгений\\2022 Работа\\202212\\20221219 тест\\1_Document.csv'
```

Пробовал:

- менял слэши \ на /;
- проверял переменные path;
- переустанавливал pyinstaller и python;
- настраивал кодировку в windows;
- менял путь, чтобы кириллицы не было (*это работает, но кириллица в пути будет*);
- паковал без флагов, и в один exe файл (-F).

Пожалуйста, подскажите как обрабатывать кириллицу в пути файлов/папок, чтобы после упаковки работало?

Windows 10 x64, Python 3.11.0, pyinstaller 5.7.0

*upd1:*

- запускал от имени администратора.

Comment: а запускаете от админа ?

Answer (score 0):

'C:\Евгений\2022 Работа\202212\20221219 тест\' папка существует на том компьютере где это запускаете?

Скорее всего этой папки нет или опечатка.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/816064)

Comment: @Pilaton является

Comment: Да, указанный путь существует, и он верный.